# Remove white space from MultiBinding StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml

Unable to remove whitespace from StringFormat.

If no 'Type' data the following whitespace doesn't fallback.

ReleaseDate, space, space, dot, space, space, Type, space (some reason it doesn't remove this space), Color

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:yyyy}  ·  {1} {2}" >
      <Binding Path="ReleaseDate" FallbackValue="{x:Null}"/>
      <Binding Path="Type" FallbackValue="{x:Null}"/>
      <Binding Path="Color" FallbackValue="{x:Null}"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: You mean you want to remove the `{1} ` part including the whitespace when Type is null?

Comment: yeah i got confused as to which one should be removed when i was testing, aplogies. it should always be "space, space, dot, space, space,"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may probably replace the MultiBinding and its StringFormat by a DataTrigger:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:yyyy}  ·  {1} {2}" >
                        <Binding Path="ReleaseDate" FallbackValue="{x:Null}"/>
                        <Binding Path="Type"/>
                        <Binding Path="Color" FallbackValue="{x:Null}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Text">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:yyyy}  ·  {1}" >
                                <Binding Path="ReleaseDate" FallbackValue="{x:Null}"/>
                                <Binding Path="Color" FallbackValue="{x:Null}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: sorry, this is correct i had to do a clean build and it worked.

Comment: I had to change <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Null}"> to <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="">.
Not sure if it was because Release Date and Color in a dropdownlist and Type was in a field and fields are not null? would like confirmation if possible.
Thanks mate

Comment: If Type is a string, it can be null or empty. You probably confused that.

Comment: then theoretically setting <Binding Path="Type" FallbackValue=""/> in the initial post would work but nope

Comment: kind regards for your assistance. if you have time would you possible know the answer to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134020/resize-ellipse-circle-with-resolution-change-responsive

Answer (score 0):

While the approach with DataTrigger works, it is very verbose. I would make it a two-step process: bind `Type` separately with a StringFormat which has a space, then bind everything together

```
<TextBlock Name="Title" 
           local:Attached.SomeString="{Binding Type, 
                                       StringFormat='\{0} ',
                                       TargetNullValue=''}">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:yyyy}  ·  {1}{2}">
            <Binding Path="Login" />
            <Binding Path="(local:Attached.SomeString)" 
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            <Binding Path="Name" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

If Type is not `null` then SomeString binding uses string format, and returns Type + space at the end. If Type is `null`, then binding return empty string.

SomeString is a reusable attached dependency property without special meaning. It declared as

```
public class Attached
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SomeString", typeof (string), typeof (Attached));

    public static void SetSomeString(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(SomeStringProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetSomeString(UIElement element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(SomeStringProperty);
    }
}
```

TextBlock has `Tag` property which can be used to store (or bind) some data, but Tag is of type `object`, and doesn't use StringFormat from binding. So I couldn't use Tag for my purpose here, and had to create another property, which has `string` type. (note also special syntax to bind attached property)

Comment: I tried this out of curiosity it still leaves the the white space in this case